# How do I convert a '.pages' file to something unix-y?

Tags: conversion, documents

I have a file with the extension '.pages´.  I *think* that means iWork, but I'm not sure.  Anyway, searching for "convert pages linux" produces a fair few false negatives!

Does anyone happen to know a way to convert it to something reasonable on Linux?

Comment: I'd be curious what the `file` command on Linux says about it.  Try `file my_odd_file.pages`

Comment: **file** reports: Zip archive data

Answer (score 7):

Pages documents are zip-compressed archives. Unzip it and you'll find an index.xml file from which you can extract the contents. There is also a [VB utility](http://pagesconvert.sourceforge.net/) on sf.net that might have more information on the XML structure.

Comment: There is no index.xml

Answer (score 5):

.pages extension designates a file created with the Apple's word processing software called "Pages". AFAIK, Pages can be bought along with other iWork (suite) tools like "Numbers" (spreadsheets) or alone.
It is able to produce PDF and RDF so if you can ask these format, just do it.

The .pages files are zipped archives. Extract it and you'll find several files, HTML, XML, images, ...

So you can't edit them but have a preview.

AFAIK there is no Pages2ODT converter.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is nothing that can read `.pages` documents on Linux. However, if you cannot obtain the document in another file format, you can register for free to Apple's iCloud service (https://www.icloud.com/), upload your document there, and download it in either .docx or .pdf format.

This is of course less than ideal, but at least you can view the document. 
A more detailed step-by-step description of the process with screenshots can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43430/how-to-open-mac-documents-page-on-libreoffice/709346#709346).

Answer (score 3):

A `.pages` document always contains a "screenshot" of the document. So you can just open that (usually called `preview.jpg`, in previous versions it was `Preview.pdf`) to view it:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

emacs!

```
emacs evilapplefile.pages
```

then click on preview.jpg

(or if the force is strong in you, do it without a mouse)

I was rather impressed how my emacs setup was able to show the subfiles and then I could view the .jpg

I think this was all with default plugins.  My emacs-fu is not so great as to have customized it much.

Emacs even opens pdf files.  (sorry if this is obvious but it was such a pleasant discovery)

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you think `emacs` is a good candidate for the solution, you may want to expand a little on whether additional (non-default) plugins are needed for the task, and if the conversion process may need manual intervention. If possible, add a link to "further reading" sites.

Comment: You can open PDF and JPG files in default emacs.  _However_, emacs a) will not convert it (as the question asks), and b) only displays the first page (the preview) if you open the `preview.jpg` file.